# Data from different records in one record using Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a database that has dr, patient, dateofservice(DOS), xxnum, distinctClaimNumber

What I need to do is for each dr, patient,xxnum, put the DOS and ClaimNumber

so:

```
dr smith     sleepy      12        1/1/10    12        1/1/11      12     1/12/11
dr smith     sleepy      14        1/1/10    14        3/1/10      14     1/1/11      14     1/12/11
dr jones     doopy       15        2/16/10   15        3/11/10
```

right now it shows

```
dr smith    sleepy  12  1/1/10
dr smith    sleepy  12  1/1/11
dr smith    sleepy  12  1/12/11
```

Comment: Are you looking for table designs or do you have tables but need to create a query?

Comment: Perhaps you are wondering about form design?

Comment: It looks like you want to find records with common fields (doctor, patient, and xxnum) and list the DOS and ClaimNumber horizontally for each claim (although it seems that claim numbers aren't present in your example). As you've already seen, Access prefers to list things down rather than across ... but if you can explain more about where you want these records (in another table? in a query? in Excel?), we can probably help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want a crosstab? You could use doctor and patient for row headings, DOS as column headings, and then concatenate the other fields for the value. You'd get something like this:

```
                  | 1/1/10  | 2/16/10 | 3/1/10  | 3/11/10  | 1/1/11  |  1/12/11
dr smith | sleepy | 12      |         |  14     |          |  12     |    12
dr smith | dopey  |         |  15     |         |  15      |         |
```

If that looks like the result you want, here's an article on office.com with more information about crosstab queries: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-select-or-crosstab-query-mdb-HP005187965.aspx 
And here's an article about crosstab reports: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-crosstab-report-HP005187407.aspx